# Need help updating back/forward button for WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` and a layout at the bottom housing the back and previous buttons. I'm looking for a way to accurately set the enabled state of these buttons depending on the `WebView`'s history. I tried the `doUpdateVisitedHistory` method in the `WebViewClient` but that only updates when a new URL is loaded...not for cases where a link simply scrolls down the current page, which apparently is still kept in the `WebView`'s history. How do I capture ALL additions to the `WebView`'s history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted( WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon ) {

        super.onPageStarted( webView, url, favicon );
        progressBar.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url ) {

        super.onPageFinished( webView, url );
        progressBar.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

        previousButton.setEnabled( view.canGoBack() );
        nextButton.setEnabled( view.canGoForward() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError( WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl ) {

        super.onReceivedError( webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl );
        Toast.makeText( BrowserActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try webView.canGoBack() and webView.canGoForward() methods ?

-Salil

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had already knew about these methods but needed to set a listener somewhere to know when exactly the browser history had been updated. I'll post what I ultimately ended up going with.